# Problem to convert Mantine Component to Plotly dash - How to represent target prop?

Tags: reactjs, components, plotly-dash, converters, mantine

I'm trying to convert the [Mantine Popover Component](https://mantine.dev/core/popover/) to a Dash component but can't understand how to represent the target correctly.

I have opened a Pull Request on Dash Mantine Repository so you can check and reproduce it in your local machine if yo want:
https://github.com/snehilvj/dash-mantine-components/pull/42

The main problem I'm facing is in the target

```
 target={target ? target : (<Button id='button-click'
                    style={{ background: 'green' }}
                    onClick={clickResponse}>Test Button</Button>)}
```

I would like to understand what would be the best way to implement this kind of behavior when converting from React to Dash?

If you need more info, please let me know... Any contribution is really appreciated